# regex for words does not containing Cyrillic letters

Tags: python, regex, cyrillic

I'd like to clean the string from any words, which does not contain at least one Cyrillic letter (by words I mean parts of string split by whitespace char)

I've tried `line = re.sub(' *^[^а-яА-Я]+ *', ' ', line)` where `[а-яА-Я]` is set of cyrrilic letters, but when processing string

```
 des поместья, de la famille Buonaparte. Non, je vous pr&#233;viens que si vous
```

it returns

```
поместья, de la famille Buonaparte. Non, je vous pr&#233;viens que si vous
```

instead of оf just

```
поместья
```

Comment: You can try `(?<!\S)[^а-яА-Я\s]+(?!\S)` and then strip the string for leading, trailing and replace gaps of double whitespaces by a single one `(?<!\S)[^а-яА-Я\s]+(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/tON23m/1

Comment: solution works as expected, despite of I'm not getting what (?<!\S) and (?!\S) mean. Thank you for usefull site btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to match 1 or more occurrences of characters that are not in the range а-яА-Я and also exclude matching whitespace characters adding `[^а-яА-Я\s]+`

The negative lookarounds `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)` assert whitespace boundaries to the left and to the right.

When replacing with an empty string, there could be double spaced gaps, that you would have to replace with a single space.

If you don't want to match the trailing comma, you can use strip and add the characters that you want to remove.

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tON23m/1) for the matches.

For example:

```
import re

s = " des поместья, de la famille Buonaparte. Non, je vous pr&#233;viens que si vous"
pattern = r"(?<!\S)[^а-яА-Я\s]+(?!\S)"
print(re.sub(pattern, "", s).strip(', '))
```

Output

```
поместья
```

Comment: The Russian letter regex is `[а-яёА-ЯЁ]`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep any non-whitespace chunks that contain at least one Cyrillic char in them.

You can `str.split()` the string and use [`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html) to check if at least one char is Cyrillic, and only keep those "words":

```py
import unicodedata as ud
result = ' '.join([word for word in text.split() if any('CYRILLIC' in ud.name(c) for c in word)])
print(result) # => поместья,
```

**If you also need to strip any punctuation** use any of the solutions from [Best way to strip punctuation from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/265960/3832970):

```py
import string
result = ' '.join([word.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)) for word in text.split() if any('CYRILLIC' in ud.name(c) for c in word)])
print(result) # => поместья
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/TCwgqw). *Details*:

- `[word.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)) for word in text.split() if any('CYRILLIC' in ud.name(c) for c in word)]` - a list comprehension that

  - `text.split()` splits the `text` into non-whitespace chunks
  - `if any('CYRILLIC' in ud.name(c) for c in word)` - condition checking if the `word` contains at least one Cyrillic char
  - `word.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))` - takes the `word` if condition above is *True* and strips punctuation from it
- `' '.join(...)` - joins the list items into a single space-separate string.

Comment: ud.name(c) isn't the best way to handle this, better to install and import unicodedataplus, a drop-in replacement for unicodedata. The latest version always uses the latest version of Unicode at the time. SO : `import unicodedataplus as ud` then you have access to `ud.script(c)` which will return the value of the script. Also, using `string.punctuation` will only move punctuation in the basic Latin block, it will not remove other punctuation.